# Which should I use: preceding:: or preceding-sibling::?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm hesitating whether to write `preceding` or `preceding-sibling` in XSL such as an example xml below.

```
<sales_division>
  <team area="Tokyo">
    <staff>Sato</staff>
    <staff>Tanaka</staff>
  </team>
  <team area="Osaka">
    <staff>Ueda</staff>
    <staff>Suzuki</staff>
  </team>
</sales_division>
```

If current node is `team(@Osaka)`, and I want to get first-child node `staff(Sato)` of `team(@Tokyo)`, what should I write Xpath appropriately?

I guess three options below.

```
1) preceding-sibling::team/staff[1]<br>
2) preceding::staff[2]<br>
3) ../team[1]/staff[1]
```

Please give me your advice and opinions.

Comment: It depends on *why* you need this. The three expressions in your example are equivalent only by coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to write a *meaningful* XPath as it is easier to read and will be easier to maintain. So, I would say I prefer the first way, since it is the closest to the English description of your intention :

```
preceding-sibling::team/staff[1]
```

or even more specific (if necessary) :

```
preceding-sibling::team[@area='Tokyo']/staff[1]
```

Also, element positions is generally less meaningful and tends to break easily upon slight changes on the XML arrangement, so I'd suggest not to rely on element position index too much.

Comment: Thank you, 'har07'. I can understand you. And I try not to use element position too much.

Comment: "*element positions is generally less meaningful*" That depends on the XML document's schema (of which we know practically nothing). It could be meaningless or it could be crucial.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me that you are (also) asking what these axes actually do. As Michael and Har already pointed out, it really depends on the larger picture whether or not to choose one over the other. In practice, the need for `preceding`, and to a lesser extend `preceding-sibling` can be a sign of code smell and their performance can be detrimental, depending on input and predicates.

Let's suppose your input is slightly different:

```
<sales_division>
  <team area="New York">
    <staff>John</staff>
  </team>
  <team area="Tokyo">
    <staff>Sato</staff>
    <staff>Tanaka</staff>
  </team>
  <staff />
  <team area="Osaka">
    <staff>Ueda</staff>
    <staff>Suzuki</staff>
  </team>
</sales_division>
```

> 1) preceding-sibling::team/staff[1]

The preceding-sibling axis is a *reverse* axis, which means it goes from bottom to top through your siblings. The `staff` step is actually `child::staff`, which is itself a forward step.

Here you are asking:

- take all preceding siblings that match `team`
- of all these, go down and select the first `staff`
- in the augmented XML, this will select "John"

> 2) preceding::staff[2]

The preceding axis is also a *reverse* axis, but instead of going over the siblings, it goes over all nodes that have already been passed (meaning: if a node is still in the present ancestor axis, it is not selected), depth first (meaning: text nodes in `staff` come before `staff` children, which come before `team` siblings).

Here you are asking:

- take all the preceding nodes that match `staff`, that is empty, Tanaka, Sato and John (in that order).
- select the second you find
- in the augmented XML, this will select Tanaka

> 3) ../team[1]/staff[1]

`..` is short for `parent::node()`. It means take the parent of the current node (which is the root element `sales_division`)

Here you are asking:

- go to the parent `sales_division`
- from there go down and find the first child matching `team`
- from there find the first child matching `staff`
- in the augmented XML, this is John

So, in conclusion, it depends on the actual XML structure. Typical use-cases for `preceding-sibling` are where the order of your XML is known and meaningful (for instance, two coordinates, where the previous sibling is longitude, the current is latitude).

In practice, I see more often that you need an element that is a sibling *before* or *after* the current node. In that case, the `..` (parent) syntax is probably the best way to go, possibly excluding the current node from the node set. This is easier in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 than in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what is in your XML, you don't need any of these expressions, you could just write "Sato". You presumably need to navigate the XML because you know something about its structure but you don't have complete knowledge of its content. So the way you navigate it is by using what you know in order to discover what you don't know. This makes it impossible for us to help you, because you haven't told us how much of the XML is variable and how much is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Michael. I think you are right. I have opportunities to convert XML to HTML in my job. So I have to write XPath in an XSLT. I wanted to know the general and understandable way to write XPath in the XSLT, and posted the example.