# Selenium XPath - how to find immediately preceding element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am running tests in Java Selenium where I find an element, and once found need to find the *immediately preceding* element. The code needs to be dynamic because I don't know if the element I start from is the 3rd out of 5, the 6th out of 10, or the 1st out of 2.

The problem is, using preceding-sibling from xpath, I get all elements preceding the found element, not the one immediately preceding it.  For example, this is my xml:

```
<div>
    <input formcontrolname="myValues" id="value1" type="radio" value="VALUE1" />
    <label for="value1">Value 1</label>
    <input formcontrolname="myValues" id="value2" type="radio" value="VALUE2" />
    <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
</div>
```

Lets say I have found the 'Value 2' label as a WebElement, then I want to do next is find the specific input immediately preceding that label (id='value2'). Since it has to be relative to the label I've found, I can't just find by that id; I don't really know the id, just that the input is supposed to precede the label. I thought I could use this:

```
WebElement input = element.findElement(By.xpath("preceding-sibling::input"));
```

But that xpath actually returns all the inputs that are siblings of the label. So, in the example, I get an array of two inputs returned, both 'value1' and 'value2'. Selenium sets the value of *input* to be the input with id='value1', the first in the returned array.

So my question is, is there an xpath that will return the one element that *immediately* precedes a given element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get required result by specifying the index:

```
./preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

In this case you'll get the first (immediate) preceding-sibling of type `"input"`

Comment: The problem is I don't know the index.  What if there are three sets of labels and inputs, instead of 2? I can't be sure of the index.

Comment: No. This is not the absolute index of element, this is the relative index and it just means "the **closest** input sibling to current node". Even if there are thousands of sets - this XPath will match the first sibling

Comment: Got it.  Works perfectly.  Thanks.

You can it here with more than 2 elements: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e6ec6df0e2f5930d44c9c3ece00fc59c

xpath = //label[@for='value4']/preceding-sibling::input[1]

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the `<input>` with `id="value2"` with respect to `<label>` with `Value 2` you can use the following `xpath` :

```
.//preceding::input[1]
```

---

### Update

I still feel you haven't been able to express/put-up your exact use-case/requirement properly. A possible use-case for you may be *to invoke `click()` on a **Radio Button** i.e. on a `<input>` tag with respect to a **Label** i.e. a `<label>` tag*. If this is your *usecase* a better way would be to write a function as follows :

```
public void click_radio_button(String label_text)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='" + label_text + "']//preceding::input[1]")).click();
}
```

Now from your `main()` or `@Test` annotated class you can call the function **`click_radio_button()`** passing the **Label Text** as an argument to `click()` on the respective **Radio Button** as follows :

```
click_radio_button("Value 1")
click_radio_button("Value 2")
```

Finally, why should you have chosen **preceding** over **preceding-sibling** ?

As per the *HTML* all of the `<input>` and `<label>` nodes are on the **same step** as follows :

```
<div>
    <input formcontrolname="myValues" id="value1" type="radio" value="VALUE1" />
    <label for="value1">Value 1</label>
    <input formcontrolname="myValues" id="value2" type="radio" value="VALUE2" />
    <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
</div>
```

Ideally,

- **preceding-sibling** should have the prototype of **`preceding-sibling::parentNode/childNode[n]`** (`which is not your usecase`)
- **preceding** should have the prototype of **`preceding::node[n]`** (`which exactly matches your usecase`)

  Here you can find a detailed discussion on [*Which should I use: preceding:: or preceding-sibling::?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900866/which-should-i-use-preceding-or-preceding-sibling)

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue though -- i don't actually know in the app I'm testing what the input's id attribute is.  All I know is that it immediately precedes the label.

Comment: see chosen answer -- basically the same as this.

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @DebanjanB , interesting thought :) So you want to say that using **`preceding-sibling`** doesn't suit much the case when OP wants to get **preceding-sibling** ? ))) `preceding-sibling`/`following-sibling` should be used exactly for these cases while `previous`/`following` - for cases when you want to get nodes on different DOM levels!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused on what you're telling to the driver to reference. 'findElement(By.xpath("preceding-sibling::input"));' isn't specifying WHAT it should precede.... so if all you're looking to do is find everything preceding any element with an id of 'value,' you're code should look something like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'value')]]/preceding-sibling::input");
```

Now the syntax assumes you know where your semi-colons, parentheticals, etc should be... I apologize in advance if my syntax isn't right. I write selenium, but only in Python.

Comment: What I do is fine the label as a WebElement, then I find the input based on that element.  So it's not `driver.findElement()`, it's `myElement.findElement()`.

so, if I did it in a single statement (using Java) it would look like:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='value1'").findElement(By.xpath("preceding-sibling::input");`