# Xpath - access penultimate node of a list with variable length?

Tags: html, xpath, reverse

I have a `div` that contains several, but a varying amount of `h3`s (as well as a lot of `p` but they can be ignored). The last `h3` has a constat value (but no `class` or `id`). There is also an `img` with some, probably unique, properties a the end of the `div`. All in all it looks something like this:

```
    <div class="article__body">
        <p>value</p>
        <h3>changing value</h3>
        <p>value</p>
        <p>value</p>
        <h3>changing value</h3>
        <h3>changing value</h3>
        *and so on for a bit*
        <h3>THIS IS THE VALUE I AM INTEREST IN</h3>
        <h3>THIS VALUE IS CONTSTANT</h3>
    ﻿   <img srcset="/siteassets/lobby.png?preset=340&amp;version=63684897580 340w">
    </div>
   </div>
   <aside class="service">
```

Can I go to either to the `h3` with the constant value, the `img` or maybe the `aside` tag outside this `div` (and one more level of `div`s) and then step back to the `h3` I am interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is simpler and also seems to work:

```
//h3[contains(text(),'CON')]/preceding-sibling::h3[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your subject question "access penultimate node of a list with variable length?" in XPath would simply translate into `//div[@class = 'article__body']/h3[last() - 1]`, i.e. in the list of `h3` children you can select the penultimate with `h3[last() - 1]`: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yi

Answer (score 1):

Try Following Xpath.

To access h3 tag with constant value

```
'//div[@class="article__body"]/h3[text()="THIS VALUE IS CONTSTANT"]'
```

OR

```
'//div[@class="article__body"]/h3[contains(.,"CONTSTANT")]'
```

To get last h3 node of a tree.

```
'(//div[@class="article__body"]/h3)[last()]'
```

To access image with srcset property.

```
'//div[@class="article__body"]/img[contains(@srcset,"/siteassets/lobby.png?preset")]'
```

**EDITED**

```
'(//div[@class="article__body"]/h3)[last()-1]'
```

OR

```
'//div[@class="article__body"]/h3[text()="THIS VALUE IS CONTSTANT"]/preceding-sibling::h3[1]'
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the previous h3 from the constant h3 or last h3?

Comment: @d-b : Please check 2 options i have provided in edited sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use easily find h3 with a constant value.
Use `preceding-sibling` xpath axis to get its predecessor.

[How to get the preceding element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857756/how-to-get-the-preceding-element)

`preceding` would also work in your case
[Which should I use: preceding:: or preceding-sibling::?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900866/which-should-i-use-preceding-or-preceding-sibling)